# A simple question about Spring IoC

Tags: java, spring, ioc-container

Let's imagine, there are 1000 classes (X1...X1000) which are all defined in a library `abc.jar`.

The X* classes have used some JSR-330 annotations, like:

```
class X12 {

    @Inject
    Foo foo;

    @Inject
    Bar bar;

}
```

My main class is a test case `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`, and the referenced `Foo`, `Bar` are well defined in the bean XML files.

The question is, I don't want to define X1...X1000 in any XML files. But I'd like to auto wire them, for example:

```
X173 x173 = new X173();
```

But the problem is, using Java new instance, foo/bar isn't wired.

This also not works:

```
X173 x173 = applicationContext.getBean(X173.class);
```

because no bean for X173 is defined.

And, X173 may also contains a member of class X258 which should be wired, too. I can't figure out how to implement it until I've resolved this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [autodetection](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-classpath-scanning) to declare them as Spring beans.

The most obvious way is to annotate these classes with Spring annotations such as `@Component` and then add `<context:component-scan />` to your XML.

If annotating is not an option, `<context:component-scan />` supports configurable filters. For example, if these classes are actually named `X1...X1000`, you can use regexp filter:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example">
     <context:include-filter type="regex" expression="com\.example\.X\d{1,4}"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the class names are arbitrary. hmm.. I think `component-scan` will get unnecessary side-effects. When I write `applicationContext.getBean(X173.class)`, I know exactly what will be injected, but `component-scan` looks rough.

Comment: @继雷'Lenik: Your problem goes against the concept of Spring, since Spring creates beans from predefined bean definitions, not in ad-hoc manner. You can create a bean without definition with `applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().createBean(X173.class)`, but it doesn't satisfy the last requirement (interdependencies of beans).

Comment: Great tip! Say F=AutowireCapableBeanFactory, then I can replace all  `new X` by `F.createBean(X.class)` in the library implementation. And that's just what I want. I think it's clear, and not against the Spring concept, anyhow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. There is different types of testing. Let's look at too of them.

- In modular testing you should test single class and mock it's dependency. So, you should avoid any injector.
- In integration  you should test some class's interaction, so you can use injector as in usual application.

Comment: For modular testing, why not just inject with mocked instance? (By specify a test-purpose context xml)

Comment: @谢继雷'Lenik, The best injection is constructor injection. So, in modular testing, you should provide some instances to constructor. It can be and should be mock's.

Comment: @谢继雷'Lenik, I didn't get "mocked instance". Can you clarify it, please.

Comment: I mean the fake instance, for example, the mocked instance for FileSystem maybe just print logs, but don't do anything harmful. Sorry for my english, HTH.

Comment: @谢继雷'Lenik, my mocking dependency I mean exactly fake instances. So I don't need do any Spring IOC in your modular tests. BTW, Sorry for my english too)